# Cakephp How to get a list of birthday within a week range from today

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a mysql 'contact' table with column 'birthdate'.
How can I get a list of contact with birthday within 1 week range from today.

```
    $sideBarTaskSuggestion = $this->Project->Contact->find('all', array(
                             'conditions' => array(
                             'Contact.group_id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.group_id'),
                             'Contact.birthdate NOT' => null,
                             'Contact.birthdate => ???1weekrange???
                             ),
                             )
                             );
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a compound condition:

```
$sideBarTaskSuggestion = $this->Project->Contact->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
    'Contact.group_id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.group_id'),
    'Contact.birthdate NOT' => null,
    'AND' => array(
        array('Contact.birthdate NOT' => null),
        array('Contact.birthdate <=' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 week'))),
        array('Contact.birthdate >=' => date('Y-m-d')),
    )
));
```

Comment: I tried it, and it does not show anything.. I think this is because you comparing everything including year. I need just the birthday.. out of birthdate..